# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/plugin/AbstractUIPlugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, headless

i have a plugin in eclipse, which is work perfect.
Now i have to implement headless plugin functionality.

I added the following code in plugin.xml

```
<extension
     id="id1"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
  <application>
     <run
           class="de.**.HeadlessPlugin">
     </run>
  </application>
```

Then i created the following class "HeadlessPlugin"

```
package de.tsystems.together.mqc.impl;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IExecutableExtensionFactory;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPlatformRunnable;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext;


public class HeadlessPlugin implements IExecutableExtensionFactory {  

    public HeadlessPlugin()
    {

    }

    public Object create() throws CoreException {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        return null;
    }  
}
```

I exported the plugin correctly and installed the same in a new eclipse instance.
Then i try to start the plugin via cmd:

```
java -jar "plugins/org.ecplise.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar" org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main -application de.***.id1
```

After this eclipse occured an error:

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in de.*** was unable to load class de.***.HeadlessPlugin.

Have anyone an idea??

Stack trace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-08-19 14:15:47.344 
!MESSAGE Application error 
!STACK 1 
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in de.** was unable to load class de.**.HeadlessPlugin. 
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle de.** (1522). 
...
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator de.**.Plugin for bundle de.** is invalid 
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/plugin/AbstractUIPlugin
```

Comment: Why was Eclipse unable to load the class `de.*.HeadlessPlugin`?

Comment: thats exactly my problem...

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: here is the stack trace http://nopaste.info/372b075ac3.html

Answer (score 0):

As the error message in the stack trace says, your plugin depends on `AbstractUIPlugin` but this bundle isn't installed.

You will have to remove all UI references from your code and try again.

Comment: Following message is in log file now:

Application "id1" could not be found in the registry.

Comment: Okay, so your original ID was correct (as suggested by The fully qualified name, with plug-in prefix, is used when referring to the application id from the other plug-in. http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fproduct_def_extpt.htm). Why was Eclipse unable to load the class de.*.HeadlessPlugin?

Comment: The fully qualified name is unique. 
this package structure is unique, too.

"Why was Eclipse unable to load the class de.*.HeadlessPlugin?"
Thats my question :D ^^